# how to insert the auto increment data type to another table c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i want to add the increment ID PRIMARY KEY to another TABLE

here is my Code

```
           int id = null; //this id is public

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1([ID], [Name] values (@ID, @Name)", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
```

add to this database
[add to this database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gefCM.png!)

```
            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table2([TableID], [OtherInfo], [OtherDocument] values (@TableID, @OtherInfo, @OtherDocument)", connection);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableIDID", id);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherInfo", txtOtherInfo.Text);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherDocument", txtOtherDocument.Text);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command2.Parameters.Clear();
```

[TAble2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDRp2.png)

i want everytime i add a new name the id field also add in other table sorry for my bad english Thanks.

Comment: i think you dont need to do add any value to that column datatype itself says its auto increment just  leave ID column

Comment: but. how do i add the autoincrement data type into another table?

Comment: You no need to increment in second table. What you can do is when you insert something in first table get the max(id) and and insert it into the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your ID field is an Autonumber, you shouldn't give value for it when you insert, You let the database create it for your

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("insert into Table1([Name] values ( @Name)", connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now the problem is how to retrieve it. This could be done using the command SELECT @@IDENTITY

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Finally you can use the retrieved ID on your insert for the other table,

This is a pattern required by MS-Access that don't understand batch commands. Other database systems have a better pattern for this using just one trip to the database instead of two. (Of course, being Access mainly a desktop database, this make no big difference)

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, it has helped a lot. :)